# Adding a view to database created by Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first

I have created my first ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

I have created my model which creates the Database (Database A). I now need to gather data from another database (Database B) which sits on the same server. I have created a view (2 columns - ID and Name called People) in Database A that shows me the data I require from Database B.

I'd like to add the view to my model and have typed the following

```
public class People
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

And added the following line to my dbContext

```
public class opsDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<tbl_Operators> Operator { get; set; } // Existing 
    public DbSet<tbl_OpsWeekInfo> OperatorWeekInfo { get; set; } // Existing 
    public DbSet<tbl_OpsDayInfo> OperatorDayInfo { get; set; } // Existing 
    public DbSet<People> People{ get; set; } // New Line  
}
```

But when i run project i get the following error

> The model backing the 'opsDBContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

I think i understand why i get the message, i just want to me able to use the SQL View in my project, how can this be done?

Please let me know if you require more info

Comment: Be careful with Views, EF does not support them very well.  It will assume all non-nullable fields are primary keys.

Answer (score 2):

When a change occurs in classes of context or in your database, when you are using EF code first, you need to run migrations commands.
Take a look in this link :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx